# Layout buttons on UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, uiscrollview

I am trying to create a page within my app where I can scroll down and see more buttons. I have a UIScrollview and a few UIButtons, but I have no idea how to lay them out so they will be below the length of the page in IB (I hope I am making sense). Basically, I dont understand how on IB you have just the size of the app, but in reality, you can lay all your content on a much longer page.

Thanks, and again, hope I am making sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IB, you can specify the size of your UIScrollView, just set its height to a longer page, then you can put the subviews wherever you like.

Comment: I see. Does the scrollview have to be on the main view? If it is, I can't access the rest of the length of it, plus the buttons are below the scrollview and I cant click on them. The only way I was able to do that (after stretching further the scroll view as you mentioned) is to take it out aside so I can see the entire view, then layout all the buttons, but now when I run, nothing showed up cause the main view is empty. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, that sounds fine, but just before running, drag your scrollview on top of the main view again.

Comment: I tried to drag it, but the main view doesn't "grab" it...it's like useless now, and I can't place it on the main view so it will "catch it"..

Comment: Ok, scratch that. I connected the scrollview to view and now it works. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm.  works fine for me.  Are you dragging in the Object list or in the diagram?  If in the object list, make sure the little blue line is indented under your main View before releasing.

Answer (score 0):

Your just set the UIScrollView's height, and select it in IB and drag up, then you can see the part in buttom